# TSLint " should be quotemark ' error in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I have facing this issue since a while WebStorm is showing this TSLint error in my Angular project how do I remove this warning its very annoying.

Please help me remove this weird error Thanks for your answers

My TSLint File

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs"],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"],
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single",
      "double"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      false,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator"
      //"check-type"
    ],

    "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"],
    "component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "no-access-missing-member": true,
    "templates-use-public": true,
    "invoke-injectable": true
  }
}
```

Comment: It dosnt solve my problem

Comment: Mine is a TSLint errors normally have 'TSLint' prefix in tooltip Please help

Comment: Post a screenshot with the error to clarify your case.